# how to Integrate cloudinary media library widget inside ckfinder or ckeditor

Tags: c#, cloudinary, ckeditor4.x, ckfinder

We have implemented ckfinder inside ckeditor and from browse server button ckfinder opens local storage folders.we are using cloudinary for images storage so,I want to open cloudinary folders when user click on browse server button. please help 
Thanks in advance

I googled ckfinder provide any support for cloudinary but did not find anything.
in ckfinder website there are only 3 plugin mentioned which is azure, amazon s3 and dropbox

please see below code sample

```
string folderName = string.Concat("/", ResourceConstants.ResourceFileRootPath, "/", objconfigure.SiteID);
                            string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority, ResourceConstants.ResourceFileRootPath);
                            config.AddBackend("default1", new LocalStorage(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(folderName)), baseUrl);
                            config.AddResourceType("Images", builder => builder.SetBackend("default1", "/"));
```

I want to assign cloudinary folders and path in config.addbackend function.
in browse server button click I want to display folders from cloudinary

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but there's a third-party package that provides an integration between CKEditor and Cloudinary's Media Library widget: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor-cloudinary-uploader-adapter
You might be able to use that, or the same methods, to integrate in your application

Comment: Fakhruddin Bharmal have you managed to do what you wanted ? How ? I want to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: yes..
I added 1 custom button inside ckeditor & on click of that button I opend new pop up & in pop up I am loading cloudinary widget

Comment: So you didn't use ckfinder button, ok. Could you share the code with the custom button and the cloudinary widget ? That would help me a lot ! Thks